# Entity Framework bind raw SQL query to model class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I got assignment to develop football table management system. I decided to do it using asp.net mvc. Only requirement is to use raw SQL queries. So that means I can't use linq or lambda. I would like to do something like this:

```
using (var context = new FootballTableContext())
{
     var players = context.Database.SqlQuery<PlayerViewModel>("SELECT Vardas, Pavarde FROM ZAIDEJAS").ToList();
}
```

but after executing this code, I Get a list of `PlayerViewModel` with `null` values.

ViewModel class:

```
public class PlayerViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Context class:

```
public class FootballTableContext : DbContext
{
    public FootballTableContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
}
```

So my question is how to bind that query to my ViewModel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
var players = dbContext.Database
    .SqlQuery<PlayerViewModel>("SELECT Vardas as FirstName, Pavarde as LastName FROM ZAIDEJAS")
    .ToList<PlayerViewModel>();
```

It is known as [SQL queries for non-entity types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: But now it won't compile: `The type arguments for method 'Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(string, params object[])' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. `

Comment: Please see my edit. I am pretty sure it will work with just `ToList()` as long as the column names have been specified. I guess you can test both ways and let me know.

Comment: Yes it works now. But maybe it is possible to add some attribute to viewmodel instead of using aliases?